# Python + Pandas + Dataframe : Generating dynamic column name for Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data['Predicted Order'] = predicted_order
print(data)
data.to_csv('smallys_ARMA.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

The Pandas dataframe `data` gets a new column `Predicted Order` in the dataframe whose values are assigned to the list `predicted_order`.

Here, I don't want to hard code the newly generated column name, now it's `Predicted Order`. I want every newly generated column takes name dynamically like this `Week_i` for i = 0,1,2 etc.

**Edit:**
This code will be run unknown number of times in future and each time it will add a new column to the dataframe.

Comment: Can you explain more? What is filled in new column? There are multiple columns `Week_1`, `Week_2` ?

Comment: @jezrael : yeah, exatly. This code will be run multiple times in future and each time it will add a new column to the dataframe.

Comment: Yes, what is added to column?

Comment: This code will be run unknown number of times in future and each time it will add a new column to the dataframe. The column name should be in this format : Week_i where i is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a thing like that:

```
numbers = range(52)
for i in numbers:
    if not "weeks_{i}" in df.columns:
        df["weeks_{i}"] = predicted_order
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use string formatting for that.

```
weeks = range(42)

for i in weeks:
     data[f'Week_{i}'] = predicted_order
```

If you are using Python < 3.6 then use `data['Week_{}'.format(i)]` instead

Comment: here u fixed a range for weeks, but this code will be run unknown number of times in future. can anything be done using add_prefix()?

Comment: It doesn't matter, the concept is the same, you can use whatever variable. It could be also inside an infinite loop having `i` incremented at each iteration. Ore you can just a random string instead, that's up to you.